# How do I force a simple_list_item_checked to have certain items checked in Java?

Tags: java, android, listview

I was writing a program which has a list of applications currently installed on the phone which is accessed from a secondary activity. This activity creates a list of applications which are currently installed, checks if any of them are in a static list, and if they are, these items get checked before any user interaction. The user can then interact with the list by tapping to check an item which then gets added to the static list.

I am using the simple_list_item_checked and the setItemChecked() function to set a particular item as checked given an index number. This was working perfectly well earlier (with an older version of the adt bundle, I believe). When I upgraded the adt bundle to the latest iteration (which I was forced to do by eclipse due to some compatibility issue between adt and the android version), it no longer works.

I've included the code below. The problematic portion is labeled. I've included the rest of it so as to provide context and the data types.

I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of weeks with no avail.

Thanks in advace!

```
public static ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterList = null;
public static String[] myStaticList = {};
public static String[] mypackages;
ListView myListView = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* Some Initialization code here  
     * .....
     * .....
     */
    arrayAdapterList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, mypackages);
    myListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapterList);

    // OnClickListener checks and unchecks the item as well as add/remove
    // from the static list
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            /* The item is checked/unchecked as well as added/removed from the static list
             * .......
             * .......
             */
        }
    });

    /**** PROBLEMATIC CODE SEGMENT *****/
    if (myStaticList.length <= 0) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Zero Count");
        for (int i = 0; i < myListView.getCount(); i++) {
            myListView.setItemChecked(i, false);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Non Zero Count " + myStaticList.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < myListView.getCount(); i++) {
            boolean shouldCheck = false;
            String temp = (String) myListView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            for (String s : myStaticList) {

                if (temp.equals(s)) {
                    shouldCheck = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            /* The program does reach up to this point and even executes
             * the setItemChecked() but no change occurs in the actual list item.
             */
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Checked: " + shouldCheck);
            myListView.setItemChecked(i, shouldCheck);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This probably isn't directly related to your question...Why do you have `static` variables? Will you have more than one instance of this `Activity` at any given time? If so, should all instances of this `Activity` share the same data?

Comment: setItemChecked is not working, or only last item is checked?

Comment: "it no longer works" -- please explain what this means.

Comment: I use static variables because I want to be able to access the "staticlist" from other activities. I have only one copy of this particular activity at any point in time. 

setItemChecked does not work at all. By "no longer works", I mean this function used to work with the earlier version of adt with the exact same set up but does not work with the version I just downloaded from the Android site. 

Thanks.

Comment: Did you set *listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);*

Comment: I've tried that before and tried it again just now but it exhibits extremely strange behavior. Suppose I open the activity and check some items, the first item I tap the item has no effect. Now, if I tap on another item, the first item gets checked. If I tap on a third item, the second item gets checked. However, when I open the activity a second time, the right items are indeed checked.

Comment: I don't think that has anything to do with the "ADT" bundle you are using. ADT is merely Eclipse, a Eclipse plugin for Android Development, a few platform tools (such as adb, fastboot, ...), and the latest Android SDK. ADT, by itself, has nothing to do with the behavior of the app. I think you mean it used to work on older versions of the Android SDK and it broke after you targeted the new version.

Comment: Miro, I think you're right. I think the adt version confused me as I updated the sdk version and it required me to upgrade the adt tools which probably confused me.

Comment: But I would prefer building for the newer version as I'm not sure which one I was using earlier.

Comment: Has anyone else seen this problem before? Still struggling with it. Thanks